# ASP.Net Core - Configuration Manager doesn't load data from Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, configurationmanager

I'm porting an app from .Net Framework to .Net Core and try to use `ConfigurationManager` from `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package to get a connection string from `Web.config`. The problem is that it only contains default connection string from `machine.config`. I know that ASP.Net Core use `appsettings.json` with `IConfiguration` as a default way to manage configuration but as I understand `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package was added to simplify the migration. So that's the right way to use `ConfigurationManager` to get the data from `Web.config` instead of global `machine.config`?

Web.config content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="My" connectionString="sample data" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the file must be named `App.config`, even if it's web app. After renaming `Web.config` to `App.config` it's read properly

Comment: Connection strings in asp.net core are normally not stored in Web.config. ASP.NET core can be used without IIS but only IIS would care about Web.config. So that is not a secure place. There are many means for storing sensible data and retrieve it in a consistent manner through _Configuration_

Comment: As I said, I know about changes in managing configuration between ASP.Net and ASP.Net Core but in case of migration of the large project it's way easier to do it step by step

Comment: I completely agree with this